# How to enable CURL when using Google Cloud Shell Editor as the local development environment?

Tags: google-app-engine, curl, google-cloud-platform, php-ini, google-cloud-shell

I am using Google `Cloud Shell Editor` as my local development environment and I can't seem to figure out how to enable `CURL`.  I have an `app.yaml` file and `php.ini` file in the root directory of the `PHP55` project.

The question is: **What is the correct way to enable CURL when using Cloud Shell Editor?**

First I read that for a "local development environment", use:

```
extension = "curl.so"
```

Then I also read that for a "Windows environment", use:

```
extension = "php_curl.dll"
```

Finally, I also read that for a "production environment", use:

```
google_app_engine.enable_curl_lite = "1"
```

No matter which of these methods I try to enable `CURL`, I keep getting this same error:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init()
```

What am I doing wrong?  How can I get `CURL` working in Google `Cloud Shell Editor`?

Answer (score 3):

The following steps will generate the following warning:

> You are running apt-get inside of Cloud
> Shell. Note that your Cloud Shell machine is ephemeral and no
> system-wide change will persist beyond session end.

You will need to repeat the install each time you startup Cloud Shell. There are scripts that can run at Cloud Shell startup to do this for you. [link](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/configuring-cloud-shell#environment_customization)

1. Do not modify php.ini - return the file back like it was.
2. Cloud Shell uses this file: `/etc/php/7.2/mods-available/curl.ini` which will be created for you.
3. Install curl: `sudo apt-get install php7.2-curl`

Comment: Thanks John.  When you say to return the file back like it was, do you mean that I should not have **any** of the three different methods enabled in php.ini ?  Does this mean I also need to update the app from PHP55 to PHP74?

Comment: 1) Do not change the PHP `php.ini` file. You will receive errors if you try to enable curl manually. The apt command will make the necessary changes. 2) Cloud Shell default version is PHP 7.2, so you will need to update your app to run on Cloud Shell OR manually install PHP 5.5 yourself, which I do not recommend and is not supported.